# Docker cron scheduled job not running

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, cron

I am trying to use a docker container based on an Alpine image to run a scheduled cron job, following this [tutorial](https://devopsheaven.com/cron/docker/alpine/linux/2017/10/30/run-cron-docker-alpine.html), but after printing the statement in my startup script, the container just exits, without running my other script.

My docker-compose service is configured as follows:

```
  cron:
    image: alpine:3.11
    command: /usr/local/startup.sh && crond -f -l 8
    volumes:
      - ./cron_tasks_folder/1min:/etc/periodic/1min/:ro
      - ./cron_tasks_folder/15min:/etc/periodic/15min/:ro
      - ./cron_tasks_folder/hourly:/etc/periodic/hourly/:ro
      - ./scripts/startup.sh:/usr/local/startup.sh:ro
```

So it runs an initial script called `startup.sh` and then starts the cron daemon. The `startup.sh` script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting startup.sh.."
echo "*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min" >> /etc/crontabs/root
crontab -l
sleep 300
```

I dropped a sleep command in there just so I could launch an interactive shell on the container and make sure everything inside it looks good. The script creates another folder for 1min scripts. I have added a test script in there, and I can verify it's there:

```
/etc/periodic/1min # ls -a
.           ..          testScript
```

The script is executable:

```
/etc/periodic/1min # ls -l testScript 
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            31 Jul 30 01:51 testScript
```

And `testScript` is just an echo statement to make sure it's working first:

```
echo "The donkey is in charge"
```

And looking at the `root` file in etc/crontabs, I see the following (I've re-run the container several times, and each time it's creating a new 1min folder, which is unnecessary, but I think not the problem here):

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly

*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
```

The echo statement in `testScript` is never printed to my terminal, and the container exits with exit code 0 shortly after starting. I want to print this statement every minute... what am I missing?

Comment: where do you think you start the cron scheduler?  `crontab -l` lists cron jobs, but it doesn't start a scheduler.  From the data you've provided, I'd say you aren't actually starting cron.

Comment: @DanielFarrell my understanding is that `&& crond -f -l 8` in the `command` of docker-compose is doing that.

Comment: Okay, right, I missed that.  But `startup.sh` will have to exit before the shell running `command` will execute crond.  Are you waiting those 5 minutes?  If I were you, I'd put `exec crond -f -l 8` in the place of the `sleep` in `startup.sh`.  Make sure you're checking the docker logs if that's not working.

Comment: That works! I get the following error now, but that's a different problem: `run-parts: can't execute '/etc/periodic/1min/testScript': Exec format error`. That being said, I can also remove the `&& crond -f -l 8` from my docker-compose command. Is this configuration acceptable practice? If you want to respond with this answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: i will provide a real answer.   Can you provide the `ENTRYPOINT`, if any, in your dockerfile?

Comment: Yep. `ENTRYPOINT ["./Run"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docker compose file you have

```
    command: /usr/local/startup.sh && crond -f -l 8
```

The intention is to run as a shell command, but it's not at all clear from the question that's what's going to happen; that depends on your `ENTRYPOINT`.  Since it's defined with `[]` brackets, not additional shell will be provided.  The `command` value will be passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Assuming that *will* become a shell command, `&&` in the shell runs the left hand side, and if that succeeds, then runs the right hand side.  So `startup.sh` needs to complete *before* `crond` is executed.   `startup.sh` ends with

```
sleep 300
```

`crond` is invoked only *after* that 300 seconds.

In either case, `crond` is either not invoked at all, or `sleep` has not been completing.  The comments show that an error starting `crond` was discovered.

Using an entrypoint such as this is standard practice to configure the environment before, or provide runtime parameters when, invoking the main executable.  To do it right, you should make sure to use `exec` to run the main executable so that it receives the signals that would otherwise go to the bash shell running the entrypoint script.

So at the end of `startup.sh`:

```
exec crond -f -l 8
```

Will *replace* the shell running `startup.sh` with `crond`, so that `crond` receives all signals (at this point the shell is gone).  It's subtle but important!

In general, keep the invocation of the application as simple as possible.  Case in point, your execution process was split between entrypoint, command, and startup script, with no clear interface between them.  You wouldn't have gotten hung up on the invocation if you had put `crond` directly into the Dockerfile and left it at that.  Sometimes arguments must be provided at runtime, but environment variables - which have *names*, not just positions - are often preferred.  This keeps invocations simple and debugging straightforward.  But, when that doesn't work, a shell script entrypoint is a great solution - just make sure to `exec` your final process!

Comment: You might consider ending the entrypoint script with `exec "$@"`, and then setting `CMD crond -f -l 8`.  This will have the same net effect, except that you can `docker run --rm -it your-image sh` to run the entrypoint setup script but end with an interactive shell instead of the cron daemon, or otherwise launch some alternative command after doing the first-time setup.

Comment: Important to note that my final error was resolved by adding the `#!/bin/sh` shebang at the top of my script rather than just the echo statement by itself.